# Why does the difference between two year's retained earnings not add up?

Tags: finance, valuation, accounting

I am looking at a company's 10-k filing history for my valuation. I have collected figures for `retained earnings`, `net income` and `dividend payments`.

I would expect:

```
retained earnings(y2) = retained earnings(y1) + Net income(y2) - Dividends(y2)
```

However this is off by a about a million (or 5%). Does anyone have any accounting insights on why this might be off??

Comment: If RE(y2) lower than expected there could have been an "impairment", i.e reduction in asset value.

Comment: Acquisitions can also mess things up.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm thinking it might also be stock buybacks, that brings the number a lot closer. Close enough for now